# Append data to all elements of object element array

Tags: for-loop, foreach, append

Having issue where my acceptData() function appends returned data to the first element #cast (lets pretend there are 4 #cast elements). How can I modify so that all the data is NOT appended to only the first element but to each of the 4?

```
   //retrieves data from ajax request
        function searchCallback(data) {
            $('#results').empty();
            $('#results').scrollTop();
            var results = data.searchResponse.results

            for (i in results){
                $('#results').append("<div id='movieTitle'>" + results[i].movie.title + "</div>" + "<div id='cast'>" + "</div>");
            }

   //check if cast result is null
            if(results[i].movie.castUri != ""){
                var cast = results[i].movie.castUri;
                sendRequest(cast);
            } 
        }   
   //makes secondary request to receive URI data in this case "cast"
        function sendRequest(cast){
            $.ajax({
                    url: cast + '&sig=' + encryptSig(),
                    dataType: "json",
                      success: acceptData
                    });
        }
    //accepts URI data
        function acceptData(data){
            var castResults = data.cast;

            for(i in castResults){
                $('.cast').append(castResults[i].name);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your problem is that you are appending data to an #id. There can only be one, so by default the program is only appending the FIRST element that matches the cast id. Break it out into multiple id's, or use classes and run an each loop to append them

Comment: yes, I try to loop through classes as you mention and the data is appended to all 4 elements. Except I am getting 4 sets of data appended to each of them